Mapping class groups and moving punctures around under isotopies
I'm reading Farb and Margalit's primer, and I'm confused as to how to treat punctures under the isotopies considered in mapping class groups.
In particular, I don't understand whether they're allowed to "move" throughout the isotopy.
In the book, it says that if we treat punctures as marked points, then "$\text{Mod}(S)$ is the group of homeomorphisms of $S$ that leave the set of marked points invariant, modulo isotopies that leave the set of marked points invariant", and I just want to make sure I have the correct price interpretation of this phrase.
Is this the correct way to understand this: if $S$ is a surface with marked points $\left\{ x_0, \ldots, x_n \right\}\subset S$ to indicate the punctures, then if we have an isotopy $H(x,t) \colon S \times I \to S$ between homeomorphisms $H(x,1)$ and $H(x,0)$, then we must have that $H(x_i,t) \in \left\{x_0, \ldots, x_n \right\}$ for all $t$?.

I ask this because on page 243, it says "Let $\varphi$ be a homeomorphism of $D^2$ that leaves invariant the set of $n$ marked points. If we forget that the marked points are distinguished, then $\varphi$ is just a homeomorphism of $D^2$ fixing $\partial D^2$ pointwise, so by the Alexander lemma, $\varphi$ is isotopic to the identity. Throughout any such isotopy the marked points move around the interior of $D^2$ and return to where they started, thus effecting a loop in $C(\mathbb{C},n)$."
In this section, it sounds like the isotopy is allowed to move the points around. Is this because we are not considering the marked points to be punctures, but simply to be marked to create a loop in $C(\mathbb{C}, n)$ in the end?

In your quote the isotopy is not required to fix the marked points, cue "If we forget the marked points are distinguished [...]."

Ok, so just to be sure, the first section that I wrote out is the correct interpretation then, right?

Seems so to me, but take this with a grain of salt since I'm not versed in the literature here.
